# What prevents iOS and iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch from having an official screen recorder?

Tags: ios, applications, screen-recording

I have searched all over Apple's help and documentation I can't find any built-in ways or App Store apps that provide screen recording.

What prevents such an app from existing? Are there any obvious technical reasons?

Comment: iPhone 4S Screen Mirroring via AirPlay + 3rd Party AirPlay Server = Screen Recording!

Answer (score 3):

The technical reason no store app has screen recording is simply that no official API is provided from Apple to developers to perform screen recording.

The hardware is clearly capable of snapping still frames and storing / processing a video feed of the screen's size, so it's probably not a purely technical reason why it's currently not a feature of the OS.

Comment: Actually, there is an API. That is how apps enabled video recording on older iPhones. The only problem is it isn't useful for screen recording because you can only record the app it is in.

Comment: Should I edit this to say "there is no public API for one app to record whatever is on the screen in that app or in general when switching to another app". The AirPlay screen mirroring API seems to be the way for this to happen going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this wasn't possible to do (see [@bmike's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38626) for reasons) before the [release of iOS 11](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208067#11) in 2017:

> ##### Other features and improvements
>
> - Control Center custom controls including accessibility, guided access, magnifier, text size, **screen recording** and Wallet

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

---

But that's now possible and here's an Apple Support article explaining how to do it. From [Record the screen on your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207935):

> #### How to record your screen
>
> 1. Go to Settings > Control Centre, then tap the Add button [image: add button icon] next to Screen Recording.
> 2. Open Control Centre on your iPhone, or on your iPad.
> 3. Tap the grey Record button [image: grey record icon], then wait for the 3-second countdown.
> 4. Exit Control Centre to record your screen.
> 5. To stop recording, open Control Centre, then tap the red Record button [image: red record icon]. Or tap the red status bar at the top of your screen and tap Stop.
>
> Go to the Photos app and select your screen recording.
>
> <sub>Some apps may not allow you to record audio or video. You can't record your screen and use screen mirroring at the same time.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Apple limits the degree to which iOS applications can communicate and "share". I'm not a developer, but I would be surprised if a screen recorder application is allowed under the rules or possible with the iOS APIs.

If this feature is important to you, send [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages_ios.html) to Apple explaining what you want and why it's important to you.